# Saving data held in a data frame produced using the "by" function

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv

I used the "by" function to calculate the correlation matrix for a large number of graphs (which have 4 varibles) and saved the result in a data frame, like so:

```
results <- by(data, data$graphNumber, cor)
```

Where:
`data` is my original graph data, `data$graphNumber` is the variable I have used to pane the results and `cor` is the function used to create the correlation matrix

A sample of `results`:

```
d$graphNumber: 1
                x          y             z           T
x               1.0000000 0.9445139   0.9967193   0.9753503
y               0.9445139 1.0000000   0.9630660   0.9853882
z               0.9967193 0.9630660   1.0000000   0.9897238
T               0.9753503 0.9853882   0.9897238   1.0000000
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
d$graphNumber: 2
                x          y          z           T
x               1.0000000 0.9075414   0.9587088   0.9140054
y               0.9075414 1.0000000   0.9833022   0.9942477
z               0.9587088 0.9833022   1.0000000   0.9768249
T               0.9140054 0.9942477   0.9768249   1.0000000
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
...
```

I now want to save my results in a CSV. I have tried using:

```
write.table(results,"data.csv")
```

But this returns an error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(results[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class '"by"' into a data.frame
```

I can write each individual matrix using:

```
write.table(results[1],"data.csv")
```

However, I would like to write all the results into one CSV file with some way of identifying which graph each matrix corresponds to.

---

Structure of results, `str(results)`:

```
List of 1013
 $ 1 : num [1:4, 1:4] 1 0.945 0.997 0.975 0.945 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "x" "y" "z" "T"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "x" "y" "z" "T"
 $ 2 : num [1:4, 1:4] 1 0.908 0.959 0.914 0.908 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "x" "y" "z" "T"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "x" "y" "z" "T"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# generate sample data
n <- 1000; graphNum <- 4
data <- data.frame(x=runif(n, 1, 100), 
                   y=runif(n, 1, 100), 
                   graphNumber=gl(graphNum,n/graphNum))
(results <- by(data[,1:2], data$graphNumber, cor))

# to data frame
(df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(results, as.data.frame)))
#               x           y
# 1.x  1.00000000 -0.13468673
# 1.y -0.13468673  1.00000000
# 2.x  1.00000000 -0.04512667
# 2.y -0.04512667  1.00000000
# 3.x  1.00000000  0.03609621
# 3.y  0.03609621  1.00000000
# 4.x  1.00000000 -0.04193474
# 4.y -0.04193474  1.00000000
```

Later, you can seperate the graphNum and Var in rownames by

```
strsplit(row.names(df), "\\.")
```

Comment: @Josh PS: Perhaps you prefer `save(results, file="test.RData")` and `load("test.RData")` instead of type conversion.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert to a `data.frame` by using `do.call` and `rbind`:

```
resultsdf <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,results))
```

but you have to fix the duplcate row names before using:

```
rownames(resultsdf) <- paste(rownames(resultsdf),rep(names(results),sapply(results,nrow)), sep=".")
```

Using the mtcars data as an example:

```
results <- by(mtcars[c("mpg","disp","hp")],mtcars$cyl,cor)

resultsdf
              mpg       disp         hp
mpg.4   1.0000000 -0.8052361 -0.5235034
disp.4 -0.8052361  1.0000000  0.4346051
hp.4   -0.5235034  0.4346051  1.0000000
mpg.6   1.0000000  0.1030827 -0.1270678
disp.6  0.1030827  1.0000000 -0.5136284
hp.6   -0.1270678 -0.5136284  1.0000000
mpg.8   1.0000000 -0.5197670 -0.2836357
disp.8 -0.5197670  1.0000000  0.1182556
hp.8   -0.2836357  0.1182556  1.0000000
```

Comment: +1 This works, but the result is still a matrix, not a data frame.

Comment: Yes, you can wrap and `as.data.frame` around it, but then there is an error with duplicate row names, so these would need to be changed.

Comment: @James this works but you cant tell which group (or graph) each matrix corresponds too. How could I include this information

Comment: @agstudy @Josh I've edited it to work correctly, and this gives grouping information in the `rownames`, but the same method to do this can also be used to add as an extra column

Comment: `do.call(rbind.data.frame, ...)` should get a `data.frame` directly.

Comment: @Arun Yes, that's a much better option!

Answer (score 0):

One option to get a `data.frame` is to use `ddply`:

```
n = 100
library(plyr)
dfx <- data.frame(
  graphNumber = c(rep('A', 8), rep('B', 15), rep('C', 6)),
  x = runif(n = 29, min = 18, max = 54),
  y = runif(n = 29, min = 18, max = 54)
)
ddply(dfx, .(graphNumber), function(x){
  cor(x[,-1])
})

 graphNumber           x           y
1           A  1.00000000  0.54914531
2           A  0.54914531  1.00000000
3           B  1.00000000 -0.02346146
4           B -0.02346146  1.00000000
5           C  1.00000000 -0.86352644
6           C -0.86352644  1.00000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You may `melt` each data frame in the list and then convert to a data frame.

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)

results <- by(mtcars[ , 1:4], list(am = mtcars[, "am"]), cor)
results
# am: 0
#             mpg        cyl       disp         hp
# mpg   1.0000000 -0.7959989 -0.7926335 -0.8315065
# cyl  -0.7959989  1.0000000  0.8294544  0.8454881
# disp -0.7926335  0.8294544  1.0000000  0.8343294
# hp   -0.8315065  0.8454881  0.8343294  1.0000000
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
#   am: 1
#             mpg        cyl       disp         hp
# mpg   1.0000000 -0.8259983 -0.8348954 -0.8006683
# cyl  -0.8259983  1.0000000  0.9408836  0.9004347
# disp -0.8348954  0.9408836  1.0000000  0.9240353
# hp   -0.8006683  0.9004347  0.9240353  1.0000000

results2 <- llply(results, melt)
results2
results3 <- ldply(results2)
results3

#    .id Var1 Var2      value
# 1    0  mpg  mpg  1.0000000
# 2    0  cyl  mpg -0.7959989
# 3    0 disp  mpg -0.7926335
# 4    0   hp  mpg -0.8315065
# 5    0  mpg  cyl -0.7959989
# 6    0  cyl  cyl  1.0000000
# ...
# 18   1  cyl  mpg -0.8259983
# 19   1 disp  mpg -0.8348954
# 20   1   hp  mpg -0.8006683
# 21   1  mpg  cyl -0.8259983
# 22   1  cyl  cyl  1.0000000
```